# Unable to get the location bound of Sketchup model using Sketchup Ruby API

Tags: ruby, gis, sketchup

I have a Sketchup 3d model that is geo-located. I can get the geo-location of the model as follows :-

```
latitude = Sketchup.active_model.attribute_dictionaries["GeoReference"]["Latitude"]

longitude = Sketchup.active_model.attribute_dictionaries["GeoReference"]["Longitude"]
```

Now i want to render this model on a 3D globe. So i need the location bounds of the 3d model.

Basically i need bounding box of the model on 2d map.

Right now i am extracting the same from the corners of a model(8 corner).

```
// This will return left-front-bottom corner.
lowerCorner = Sketchup.active_model.bounds.corner(0)
// This will return right-back-top corner.
upperCorner = Skectup.active_model.bounds.corner(6)
```

But it returns simple geometrical points in meters, inches depending upon the model.

For example i uploaded [**this**](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=8bd19f4a119ec1b9c96a646c5f2af8d0) model in sketchup.  Following are the values of **geo-location**, **lowerCorner** and **upperCorner** respectively that i'm getting by using the above code for the above model.

```
geoLocation : 25.141407985864, 55.18563969191 //lat,long
lowerCorner : (-9483.01089", -6412.376053", -162.609524") // In inches
upperCorner : (-9483.01089", 6479.387909", 12882.651999") // In inches
```

So my first question is what i'm doing is correct or not ?
Second question is If *yes* for the first how can i get the values of lowerCorner and upperCorner in lat long format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it returns simple geometrical points in meters, inches depending upon the model.

[`Geom::BoundingBox.corner`](http://ruby.sketchup.com/Geom/BoundingBox.html#corner-instance_method) returns a `Geom::Point3d`. The x, y and z members of that is a [`Length`](http://ruby.sketchup.com/Length.html). That is always returning the internal value of SketchUp which is inches.

However, when you use `Length.to_s` it will use the current model's unit settings and format the values into that. When you call `Geom::Point3d.to_s` it will use `Length.to_s`. On the other hand, if you call `Geom::Point3d.inspect` it will print the internal units (inches) without formatting.

Instead of tapping into the attributes of the model directly like that I recommend you use the API methods of geo-location: [`Sketchup::Model.georeferenced?`](http://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Model.html#georeferenced%3F-instance_method)

By the sound of it you might find [`Sketchup::Model.point_to_latlong`](http://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Model.html#point_to_latlong-instance_method) useful.

Example - I geolocated a SketchUp model to the town square of [Trondheim, Norway](https://www.google.no/maps/place/Trondheim/@63.430277,10.3943408,18z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x466d319747037e53:0xbf7c8288f3cf3d4!8m2!3d63.4305149!4d10.3950528) (Geolocation: [63°25′47″N 10°23′36″E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trondheim)):

```
model = Sketchup.active_model
bounds = model.bounds
# Get the base of the boundingbox. No need to get the top - as the
# result doesn't contain altiture information.
(0..3).each { |i|
  pt = bounds.corner(i)
  latlong = model.point_to_latlong(pt)
  latitude = latlong.x.to_f
  longitude = latlong.y.to_f
  puts "#{pt.inspect} => #{longitude}, #{latitude}"
}
```

[image: showing a localised su model getting world coordinates from model coordinates]